# How setTimeout work in javascript (theoretically)

Tags: javascript

Why `setTimeout` is fired function after `alert(2)` even if I set time to 0. I thought javascript is synchronous language.

I just want to know theoretically how asynchronous work in javascript. When javascript `interpreator` encountered `setTimeout`  then what happens and when it encountered other function then what happens

**Edit :**

```
setTimeout(function(){
alert(0)
},0)


alert(1)
alert(2)
```

Comment: There is an event loop.  Check this out: http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/

Comment: `setTimeout` is a synthetic deferral and functions invoked in it will not be invoked synchronously, even if the time out is set to 0. They will be invoked (at earliest) after the current callstack is cleared (i.e, next event loop iteration). This is a good thing - it prevents the release of [H̵͘͡e ̡wh́o͠ ̶Prom̀͟͝i̴s̀es̀ o҉̶nl̨͟y̧ ̛̛m̴͠͝a̡̛͢d̡n̴̡e͝s̸s͠, T̢҉̸h̴̷̸̢ȩ͡ ͘͠N͢͢e͏͏͢͠z̛͏͜p̸̀̕͠ȩ́͝͝r҉̛́͠d̴̀i̴̕҉͞a̴̡͝͠n̢͜͟͢͟ ̶̴̢͝h̷̕͠í̸̧̛͜v̶̢͢͡e̕͡-̸̀͝m̷͜i̛͘͞ņ̛͘͟҉d̶̶̡̧͜ ̷̛͞o̵̢͘͟͞f̶̢̀͢͢ ̶̧͟͡c̕͝h̶̀͘͘à͏o҉̴́͢s̸͘͘͝͞ (or Zalgo)](http://blog.izs.me/post/59142742143/designing-apis-for-asynchrony).

Comment: @amit Given your edit, the expected execution would be alerts for 1, 2 and 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript works with an event loop to execute code. This loop takes events from a queue and executes the code attached to it.

In your current event you call `setTimeout` and put a new event in that queue. The `setTimeout` call returns immediately (the function is not executed, simply put in the queue).

Then you continue executing your current code until finished with the current event (I assume your call to `alert()`is here).

Once your current event is finished, the loop picks the next one from the queue; and that would be the function you set with `setTimeout`.

Comment: I assume that this is queue['setTimeout','alert(1)','alert(2)']. when setTimeout encountered it return false then loop goes to next event. So when it will return to setTimeout.

Comment: @amit Not really. The queue starts with ```[your code]```, where ```your code``` are the three statements setTimeout-alert1-alert2. Upon executing the first of the statements (setTimeout), your queue is ```[your code (running), alert 0]```. Your code continues running the other 2 pending statements (alert 1 and 2) and finishes. Your code is removed from the queue and the next event (alert 0) is executed.

Comment: so once they executed they removed from queue?

Comment: Yes. Actually removing the event from the queue at the beginning or at the end of the execution is an internal design decision of the JavaScript engine vendor. But the key is that all your code gets into a queue and the event loop consumes/executes those entries. By calling ```setTimout``` you may feed the queue.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is single threaded. JS will try to come as close as possible to the timeout time provided to the setTimeout function, but will only fire if the thread is not busy with something else (like waiting for the user to click `OK` in an alert popup).

So if you have a JS script that takes a long time to run and in it there are a couple if timeouts with different timeout lengths they can only fire when the JS thread is done with the rest of the code in that script.

Comment: If I understand, setTimeout would added in queue of callback and  browser asks everytime the question: What is waiting to be executed?

Comment: `alert` blocks the execution (like the `sleep` statement in PHP), so the thread is actually busy doing nothing. It simply waits for the user to click the `OK` button before it picks up where it left off. I suggest you read the text in the link that was already mentioned in the comments. It's a good read. http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/